# How to list all dependencies of a package from maven (including scopes)

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a graph with 40K artifacts and I can list all possible dependencies of a package (I do so by parsing a list of effective poms)

For example, I have the following for this package:[image]

There's 2 dependencies without taking in mind different versions.
I would like to show that this results are valid by showing that maven also lists these dependencies for this package. But when I use `mvn dependency:tree` after I add the `com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1`, I get no dependencies listed.

This is the pom file of the package:[image]

It clearly has those 2 dependencies, but their scopes are provided. Even if I use `-Dinclude=provided` or `-Dscope=provided` as a parameter, I still cannot list them.
So, how do I list all dependencies of a package no matter the scope used?

Comment: Do we talk about a package (java package) or an artifacts (groupId, artifactId, version) ?

Comment: Please do not show code as picture

Answer (score 1):

Use **Analyze Dependencies...** [action](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/work-with-maven-dependencies.html#dependency_analyzer) in the Maven tool window:

[image]

It will show the list of dependencies in the project with their scopes and usages in project:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Scope [`provided`](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#dependency-scope) means it's provided at runtime, which implies that it's not a package dependency:

> A dependency with this scope is added to the classpath used for compilation and test, but not the runtime classpath. It is not transitive.

Comment: Yes. Is there a way to show it? Because in my graph, I consider all scopes

Comment: But why you even care about it, when it's literally none of your business? eg. [`javax.inject`](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.inject/javax.inject) doesn't even have dependencies. And as stated, it's not a package dependency.

Comment: It is for a project I am working on, for my paper. I am not saying I feel this is useful or not, but it is what was requested of me from my supervisor. I need to validate somehow that my data is correct, and that is by showing that the dependencies I get from the graph can also be seen using the repo manager. 
`javax.inject` has no dependencies, correct. But `com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1` depends on it, even if its scope is provided. I just need to find a way to show that `com.google.guava:guava:14.0.1` or any other package from my graph has the correct dependencies

Comment: One can view them all on `mavenCentral()`. And these dependencies seem outdated. `14.0.1` is from 2013: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava-parent ...maybe get yourself familiar with how dependency scopes work, before writing a a paper about it. And how do you even define "correct"?

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava/14.0.1, its not from the parent :)